# mysqldump and crontab(linux)

Tags: linux, mysql

I want to make an automatic backup of my database, so i wrote like this

```
00 10   * * *   root     mysqldump -u root -ppasswordD billing "/home/backup/database_`date '+%m-%d-%Y'`.sql"
```

But it is not working, any ideas please?

Thanks and regards,

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Mind Reader or Crystal Ball](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128551/172496)

Comment: Can you tell me what information you need more ? I think it is clear enough to be understood!

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"?

Comment: It is not creating a backup file.

Comment: How do you know it is "not working"?  Does it produce error messages?  If so, what are they?

Comment: It is not creating a backup file. No it is not producing any error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
00 10 * * * mysqldump -u root -ppasswordD billing "/home/backup/database_`date '+%m-%d-%Y'`.sql"
```

If it fails or produces any output then you will get a mail for root, read it with the command "mail" or read /var/log/cron.log ;)