# PHP exec() and filesystem permissions

Tags: php, file, permissions, exec

So im new to exec and recently wanted to auutomate mysql Dumping via a php script.

My php file originates from

```
var/WWW/html/tool/script.php
```

The folder reads `root / WWW-data` when i do `ls -l`

It is doing

```
exec('mysqldump -user=user --password=pass db > selfDir\dump.sql')
```

Now what i would expect is the for the script to output to dump.sql inside the scripts Folder.
This is not Happening though.

Only once i did `touch dump.sql` and `chmod 777 dump.sql` was the dump actually being written.

I dont understand why. How can i alter my `exec()` to make sure it can CREATE the dump.file instead of only writing to it once it already exists ?

thanks

Comment: Under which user is PHP running? What permissions does the folder have?

Comment: Are you running your script via CLI or webserver?

Comment: @Kerbholz it is a Hetzner webserver
The Folder permissions arewritten above, root / WWW-data.
The php file in question is being run from localhost .. ?

Comment: @tkausl already asked (and you didn't answer), so, what are the folders permissions? Try `chmod g+w selfDir` to make it writable for the group (www-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to automatize the database backup, it's better calling the mysqldump with any other system service, like cron.

Rely on php exec can generate too many errors.

- Php limit time execution
- Execute from request, then the request is killed the exec is killed or need to wait all the mysqldump time
- More difficult permissions
- Limitation memory in php and the server

In cron you the backup will be (example from [The Java Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24236017/1439165)):

```
0 0 * * * mysqldump -u 'username' -p'password' DBNAME > /home/eric/db_backup/liveDB_`date +\%Y\%m\%d_\%H\%M`.sql
```

Other link for crontab backup with mysql: [Answer K1773R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10310907/1439165) [mysql-dump-cronjob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771166/mysql-dump-cronjob)